# RAM Kingston. Не работают одновременно планки KVR1333D3LD4R9S/8G и KVR1333D3E9S/8G

Tags: железо, ram

Материнская плата Supermicro x8dtn+ ( https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/QPI/5500/X8DTN_.cfm?IPMI=O ) . 
Память KVR1333D3LD4R9S/8G установлена в слоты:

```
P1 DIMM3A
P1 DIMM2A
P1 DIMM1A
P2 DIMM1A
P2 DIMM2A
P2 DIMM3A
```

Попытка установить модуль KVR1333D3E9S/8G в слот P1 DIMM1B приводит к тому что сервер не стартует. Если оставить только KVR1333D3E9S/8G - то сервер включается.

Как добиться того чтобы оба вида памяти работали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KVR1333D3LD4R9S/8G](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3E9S_8G.pdf) регистровая , а
[KVR1333D3E9S/8G](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3LD4R9S_8G.pdf) не регистровая , она просто ECC, вместе работать небудут.

Comment: Порекомендуйте память совместимую с KVR1333D3LD4R9S/8G для дополнительной установки в сервер.

Comment: Ну любую с похожими характеристиками, то есть: 1333Mhz и CL9, обязательно двухранковую , то есть 2Rx2 и можно L, то есть не 1,5в а 1,35в, обычно её называют PC3L

Comment: ps: сложно сказать конкретную модель незная где и как она будет покупаться. Я себе беру на eBay, получается 7-8 т.р. за 64GB